# React google-maps grey box rendered

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, reactjs

I am trying to get google maps to render in a react component. It does render a grey box and something is working as I'm getting message "Use two fingers to move the map" when trying to pan. It's just the map itself which is not showing up.

In the Map.css file I've only set .map and .mapCanvas width and height 100%. I have a feeling the problem could have something to do with CSS.

Any ideas?

Here's my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Script from 'react-load-script';

import './Map.css';

interface MapContainerState {
    scriptError: boolean
}

export default class MapContainer extends React.Component<{}, MapContainerState> {


    private mapCanvas: HTMLDivElement | null;
    private map: google.maps.Map | null;

    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            scriptError: false
        }

        this.mapLoadError = this.mapLoadError.bind(this);
        this.loadMap = this.loadMap.bind(this);
    }


    mapLoadError() {
        this.setState({
            scriptError: true
        })
    }


    loadMap() {
        const mapOptions = {
            center: {
                lat: -25.363,
                lng: 131.044
            },
            initialZoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    }



    render() {
        const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MyKey]'
        return (
            <div className="map">
                <Script 
                    url={url}
                    onError={this.mapLoadError}
                    onLoad={this.loadMap}
                />
                <div ref={ref => this.mapCanvas = ref} className="mapCanvas"></div>
            </div>

        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you search for [previous questions on this problem](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=grey+box+stackoverflow+google+maps&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english)?

Comment: I did. None of those helped me.